# ext3 Journalling

Tags: ext3

Does only the metadata get journalled in ext3 or does the data get journalled too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the *mount* manpage:

> **data={journal|ordered|writeback}**
>   Specifies the journalling mode for file data.  Metadata is always journaled.  To use modes other than **ordered** on the root filesystem, pass the mode to the kernel as boot parameter, e.g.  *rootflags=data=journal*.
>   **journal**
>   All data is committed into the journal prior to being written into the main filesystem.
>   **ordered**
>   This is the default mode.  All data is forced directly out to the main file system prior to its metadata being committed to the journal.
>   **writeback**
>   Data ordering is not preserved - data may be written into the main filesystem after its metadata has been committed to the journal.  This is rumoured to be the highest-throughput option.  It guarantees internal filesystem integrity, however it can allow old data to appear in files after a crash and journal recovery.

Answer (score 2):

By default only metadata, with the data=journal mount option, both data and metadata.

Answer (score 1):

You get to choose, with a mount option. By default, it is metadata only.